# HD video capture gameplay?

Tags: video, game-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to make a trailer…](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/tools-to-make-a-trailer)

I've developed some 3d experiences using unity3d and they are pretty much experimental at this level. Now the problem is that I need to make video captures in HD to showcase them. 
I've tried Camtasia 7 with divx compression, and still the quality is not Up to standard and number of dropframes are quite high. I'm running on a Core i7 cpu with geforce GT240. So I was thinking If it's possible to capturing the video remotely so one pc is in charge of capturing and one running the application. 
Or is there any better way to get the highest quality with least dropframes?
Number of draw calls are around 2k(I know sounds crazy, but I can't make changes right now.)

Grazies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone that I know (me included) uses [FRAPS](http://www.google.fr/search?q=fraps&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).
It's generally very good but unfortunately not very free...
We used FRAPS for our end of year project (shameless plug), no mocking!

[Heart of Paper](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S96ICu-o7-Y)

Comment: Dude this is awesome!! I was just about to give up.

Answer (score 1):

If Fraps doesn't cut it, a hardware capture card should - something like the famous Blackmagic Intensity Pro card (or Shuttle USB 3.0) that can capture HDMI (hence also DVI) up to 1080i50/60 at a bargain-bin $199 price point.

It's actually a lot more expensive to try and capture a VGA signal as far as I know... analog VGA capture beyond very low resolutions tend to be a lot more expensive than an Intensity card and not produce anywhere near as good a result.

Comment: I seem to recall it being a problem with analog sync, that needs to be recreated by a specific piece of hardware to recreate the output as a digital image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any good capturing program or not but there are two ways to minimize framedrop:

one is to attach your pc vga output to another device (like dvdplayer or satelite receiver or any other device that can capture video) and use that as a capturing device.

second one is something that i won't go with it myself and it's to get a copy of video buffer in your code back to cpu and then save it. it also slows your program but much less compared to capturing applications.